# SQL Average from multiple tables based on datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL Database with measured temperatures from three different sensors. On every update of the sensor, the new temperature is written to the database. So there are different timestamps for each value.

I would like to calculate the average temperature of the three rooms for every timestamp. Is there any SQL-Query to do this?

```
Table A: timestamp + value
0000-00-00 00:00:00.000 19.6
2018-01-22 20:45:31.594 19.6
2018-01-22 20:48:20.344 19.7
2018-01-22 20:50:54.567 19.8
2018-01-22 20:53:14.594 19.9
2018-01-22 20:55:20.087 20.0

Table B: timestamp + value
0000-00-00 00:00:00.000 18.4
2018-01-22 20:50:53.700 18.4
2018-01-22 20:53:38.417 18.5
2018-01-22 20:56:08.668 18.6
2018-01-22 20:58:24.422 18.7
2018-01-22 21:00:25.707 18.8

Table C: timestamp + value
0000-00-00 00:00:00.000 20.1
2018-01-22 20:47:07.669 20.1
2018-01-22 20:49:32.196 20.2
2018-01-22 20:49:42.184 20.2
2018-01-22 20:51:42.177 20.2

Result:
2018-01-22 20:45:31.594 (19.6+18.4+20.1)/3
2018-01-22 20:47:07.669 (19.6+18.4+20.1)/3
2018-01-22 20:48:20.344 (19.7+18.4+20.1)/3
2018-01-22 20:49:32.196 (19.7+18.4+20.2(/3
…
```

Comment: How do you match the times between the tables? Is there an ID across all 3? Or are you able to assume that each row can be joined by their ordinal numbers? Because in your result you use the time from table A, which correlates to row 2, what happened to the average for row 1 at time 0?

Comment: I have no id across all 3. I only have "timestamp" as id. For row1 there should also be an average. I'll add it. 

I would like to calculate the average without normalizing everything. Assuming we have TableC and a certain timestamp, i would like to build the average with the last timestamp from table A and table B before that timestamp.

Comment: But how are you grouping them? Is it the first row from each table matches the first row in other tables, and the second row from each table matches the second row in the other tables, as JacobH suggested? 20:45:31.594 only exists in one of your tables, so how do you know which row from the other tables matches it?

Comment: Assuming we have table C and a certain timestamp '2018-01-22 20:51:42.177', i would like to build the average with the last timestamp from table A and table B before that timestamp from table C. Should be the following: table B: '2018-01-22 20:50:53.700' and table A: '2018-01-22 20:50:54.567'    plus vice versa  for the other tables

Answer (score 0):

Join all three tables using timestamp and find then calculate the average of temperature.

Select T1.TIMESTAMP, (T1.VAL+T2.VAL+T3.VAL)/3 AS AVG_TEMP FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.TIMESTAMP=T2.TIMESTAMP JOIN T3 ON T1.TIMESTAMP = T3.TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

If you will be adding sensors to your system, you will probably want to create a single consolidated table for them. But this will work for three sensors:

```
select timestamp, avg(value) as average_value from (
select timestamp, value from table_a
union all
select timestamp, value from table_b
union all
select timestamp, value from table_c
)
group by timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming we have table C and a certain timestamp '2018-01-22 20:51:42.177', i would like to build the average with the last timestamp from table A and table B before that timestamp from table C. Should be the following: table B: '2018-01-22 20:50:53.700' and table A: '2018-01-22 20:50:54.567' plus vice versa for the other tables

How about this:

```
select
  c.timestamp,
  (
    c.value
    + (select coalesce(min(b.value),0.0) from b where b.timestamp =
        (select max(b2.timestamp) from b as b2
         where b2.timestamp <= c.timestamp))
    + (select coalesce(min(a.value),0.0) from a where a.timestamp =
        (select max(a2.timestamp) from a as a2
         where a2.timestamp <= c.timestamp))
  ) / 3 as average
from c
```